# Hebrew text in English LyX file

Tags: lyx, linguistics, hebrew

I have a LyX paper that needs some text (specifically, text within a table) to be in Hebrew. Culmus is installed, language hebrew is mapped to F10. linguistics module is activated.

When I try to compile, I get the error "missing number, treated as zero". So far as I can tell, the problem seems to be having numbered examples (or subexamples, possibly glosses as well) while having Hebrew in the text. Are the linguistics module and the language clashing somehow? How can I solve it if so?

redacted version that won't compile:

```
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\begin_preamble

\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
linguistics
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language british
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\float_placement H
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Numbered Example (multiline)
at some level, because the relation between
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="3" columns="2">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Identity
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Forward mask
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
########
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Prime
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang hebrew
תזמורת
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard

\end_layout

\end_body
```

Comment: Also, why does my code not appear as code, despite putting it between `?

Comment: Backticks work for inline code, and in comments. For blocks of code, you have to indent by four spaces (and leave an empty line before the block, I think). But you can just select the text and click the button marked `{}`.

Comment: There is no `\end_document` in your .lyx file. It is either truncated or corrupted. Can you paste a minimal example of the entire .lyx file?

Answer (score 2):

If in Hebrew you mean cardinals then you can use `\aleph` and any other similar tags. If you need writing paragraphs, for me worked using the following tutorial for LyX from Hebrew university in Jerusalem: http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~sameti/tex/lyxhebrew.html . This fix works great at least in my distribution of LyX. However math-fields in your lyx file will still tend to reverse your order of letters in hebrew.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the setup I have. The problem, however, is not with Hebrew in general - I can write in Hebrew in LyX. The problem seems to be with using the linguistics module with Hebrew in the text.
I need a number of whole words, so diacritics may be possible, but would be a lot of work. Another possibility would be to write it in another program and insert an image, but I really want to be able to use both the linguistics module and Hebrew in the future, as I use both of them regularly.