# I need occasional Hebrew letters in my English text

Tags: lyx, languages, hebrew

I am writing a humanities work in book format with LyX 2.1.2 in Linux Mint 17. I need text output in PDF format in an English language document with a few occasional words in Greek, and Hebrew.

I managed to successfully export in pdflatex the English and Greek text correctly, because the document language is English, and the entire Greek alphabet is available from Insert/Special Character/Symbols (clumsy but works). However there are only four (4) Hebrew letters available as Symbols (How do you add the entire Hebrew alphabet to the Symbols?).

If I switch to a Hebrew keyboard, I can enter all of the characters I need into the LyX editor, but when I try to export the result into pdf, LyX can not recognize the Hebrew letters I typed into my text. LyX does recognize and export to pdf the four Hebrew letters available in the Symbols menu.

In other words, how can I input more than only the 4 available Hebrew characters available as "Special Characters" under "Input".

Please be descriptive in your answer (eg. I can copy your scripts into my document), because I am a noob in LaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to [What's a simple way to typeset a small amount of Hebrew content using TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14777) and [Hebrew text in English LyX file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134705). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why.

Comment: The Hebrew input in my English document amounts to only a few words. LaTex scripts can do it, but it would be easier to have the Hebrew alphabet available as Special Characters in LyX.

Comment: @VilisLietuvietis you mean you do not want to be able to enter Hebrew directly from the keyboard for those few words?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170476/how-to-get-aleph-and-beth-symbols-in-similar-font

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple solution is to use XeLaTeX to typeset unicode characters directly. That way you will have your foreign language characters in their native script in LyX. The key is to turn on "Use non-TeX fonts (via XeTeX/LuaTeX) in the "Fonts" tab of your document's settings.

See my answer to [Two fonts for two languages using lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203078/two-fonts-for-two-languages-using-lyx) where I provide a sample LyX document.

Copy the example, paste it into a new text document and save it with a .lyx extension using a plain text editor, then open the saved file in LyX.

To enter foreign text you can copy and paste from other sources, e.g. web pages, set up an appropriate (Hebrew) keyboard, or copy and paste from an app like "Character Map".

Comment: Your solution worked better than I had hoped for, giving total freedom of entry of Greek and Hebrew text into my English LyX document.

Comment: I'm pleased it worked so well for you